# How do you create an XML document from an XSD Schema at runtime in modern c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I know that there are some pre-existing questions on SO that basically ask the same thing for offline data generation, but I would really like to find a good way to do this at runtime in modern C#.

I know about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx (XmlSampleGenerator) but that is from the .Net 2.0 days...is there anything that is a little more modern?

I've also looked at LinqToSql but I'm not seeing an easy way to do this...maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: _"a little more modern"_ - is `XmlSampleGenerator` lacking in some way?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It comes up every now and then. I have a couple of different applications that I integrated with that have EAV style schemas so the objects that you interact with are dynamic in nature and it would be nice to be able to easily create objects from those schemas.

Comment: @Gusdor It's kind of painful to use...I guess I was hoping that there was something a little easier to use.